# Headers modification using Karate

Tags: header, karate

I am running API execution using Scenario Outline and csv and want to edit header in the below format where i need to change the requestorid each and every time for the execution.
If the headers uses below format and saved in .js and tried saving it in .json file:

`"ID-HEADERS" :"{ 'requestorId': '1111', 'authMethod': 'basic'}"`

And used below lines to edit the header which is not working:

```
function() {
         var fun = karate.read(headersFilePath + 'headers.js');
         var res = fun();
         res['ID-HEADERS.requestorId'] = requestorId;
         return res;
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to set one header don't complicate it with JS:

```
Scenario Outline:
* url 'https://httpbin.org/anything'
* header foo = bar
* method get

Examples:
| bar |
| one |
| two |
```

Try it, and see the logs and HTML report. And read the documentation also.

Comment: No similar way I have multiple headers and its  in complex type as map or json fashion , so is it possible to modify the map type header value "ID-HEADERS" :"{ 'requestorId': '1111', 'authMethod': 'basic'}"

Comment: @NAMBIKATHIRUMALAI not it is not possible